# How can I add my custom style for my bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

## HTML code

```
<!-- navigation bar start -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## CSS code

```
.navbar{
   height: 500px;
}
```

---

The CSS is not applied to the navbar, why and how can I ?

Comment: Try `height: 500px !important`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but its not working.

Comment: Sorry Alorika, it was my bug that was stopping your answer to work. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap and adding your own `css` rules than you will need to overwrite the styles your adding with

`!important`

If you want to go into bootstrap and change the elements you would not have to use `!important`

So if you add your own css to your own css file you will include your css file to the project

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/my/style.css">
</head>
```

and add the tag to your css

```
.navbar{
   height: 500px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Modify your .css file**

```
 .navbar{
   height: 500px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   }
```

just add color to your navbar and it would be visible.